# Deserialize uncorrect json string

Tags: c#, json

I have small method for checking JSON string from server :

```
public virtual bool DeSerializeResponse<ResponsedBodyType>(string RespBody)
{
   var responsedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponsedBodyType>(RespBody);
       if (responsedBody == null)
           return false;
       else
           return true;
}
```

I call this method some like this :

```
bool Flag = DeSerializeResponse<SuccesType>("json_string");
```

So, if I got correct response from server - I successful create object `SuccesType` with not empty properties. But if server sent  to me  different `JSON` string then I still get `responsedBody` is not `NULL` object, although all its properties are empty. How can I check the response string is correct type?

UPD:

```
public class SuccesType
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}

public class ServerError
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string reason { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your json?

Comment: Check the type?  Example straight from Mickeysoft : int i = 0;  
System.Type type = i.GetType();

Comment: You can replace your if/else with `return responsedBody == null`

Comment: Basically just get the typename of whatever it serializes, also you can use reflection to enumerate the properties.

Comment: @Trey the problem is - I don't know which one  exactly JSON will be sent from server. and if JSON string matches `ServerError` (or another) than responsedBody must be null.

Comment: So those are the only two types? SuccesType or ServerError?

Comment: I'd just use a simple string comparison..like .Contains..or .Indexofany etc

Comment: @Trey At now already 3 (+ "SessionEspired") and may by more in future. I know - i can check string but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class SuccesType
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}

public class ServerError
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string reason { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string details { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Jsonstr = @"{ ""accesstoken"":""test access token"", ""token_type"":""token test"" }";
        bool testdeseralize = DeSerializeResponse<SuccesType>(Jsonstr);
    }

    private static bool DeSerializeResponse<T>(string RespBody)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings testSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        testSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        try
        {
            var responsedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(RespBody, testSettings);
        }
        catch(JsonSerializationException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```